# Combination Sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binary

> A combination on $n$ objects can be represented by an
>   $n$ bit binary vector, $(X_n, X_{n-1}, \dots, X_2, X_1)$,  where each bit,
>   $X_k \in \{1, 0\}$, expresses whether the corresponding object is
>   included in the combination or not. A set of combinations
>   can be represented by a set of the $n$ bit binary vectors.
>   We call such sets combination sets. Combination sets can
>   be regarded as subsets of the power set on $n$ object.
>
> We can represent a combination set with a Boolean function by using n
>   input variables for each bit of the vector. The output value of the
>   function expresses whether each combination specified by the input
>   variables are included in the set or not. Such Boolean functions are
>   called *characteristic functions*. The operations of sets, such as
>   union, intersection, and difference, can be executed by logic
>   operations on *characteristic functions*.

Can anyone please make me understand this *combination sets* with an example?

Can anyone please make me understand this *characteristic functions* with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example. Let $n=4$, and let the objects be (in order) $Alice, Bob, Carol, Dan$.

Then the combination $\{ Alice, Carol \}$ is represented by the vector $(1, 0, 1, 0)$.

The first $1$ means that $Alice$ (the first object) is in the combination.
The second digit is $0$: this means that $Bob$ (the second object)is not in the combination.

And so on.

In the same way, every binary vector represents a combination. For example the vector $(0,1,1,1)$ represents the combination $\{ Bob, Carol, Dan\}$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the power set here?

Comment: @zaki The power set is the set of all subsets of a set.  In Crostul's example, it is represented by the set of all $2^4 = 16$ four-bit binary vectors.

Comment: @Crostul  

Please check the edited question and help me if you can; Thanks!

Comment: @N. F. Taussig

Please check the edited question and help me if you can; Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic function corresponding to a subset $A\subset \{0,1\}^n$ is a function $\mathsf 1_A:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ where $\mathsf 1_A(x)= 1$ if $x\in A$ and $\mathsf 1_A(x) = 0$ if $x\notin A$. The union $A\cup B$ can be represented by $\mathsf 1_A\vee \mathsf 1_B$, the intersection $A\cap B$ by $\mathsf 1_A\wedge \mathsf 1_B$, and the complement $\{0,1\}^n\setminus C$ by $\mathsf 1_{\{0,1\}^n}\wedge\lnot \mathsf 1_C$.