# Characteristic functions..Please explain

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binary

This question is from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488884/combination-sets).

> A combination on $n$ objects can be represented by an
>   $n$ bit binary vector, $(X_n, X_{n-1}, \dots, X_2, X_1)$,  where each bit,
>   $X_k \in \{1, 0\}$, expresses whether the corresponding object is
>   included in the combination or not. A set of combinations
>   can be represented by a set of the $n$ bit binary vectors.
>   We call such sets combination sets. Combination sets can
>   be regarded as subsets of the power set on $n$ object.
>
> We can represent a combination set with a Boolean function by using n
>   input variables for each bit of the vector. The output value of the
>   function expresses whether each combination specified by the input
>   variables are included in the set or not. Such Boolean functions are
>   called *characteristic functions*. The operations of sets, such as
>   union, intersection, and difference, can be executed by logic
>   operations on *characteristic functions*.

Can anyone please make me understand this *characteristic functions* with an example?